# List all monotonic boolean functions

Tags: logic, binary, boolean, fusion-systems

I seek a Matlab or easily-to-translate function that lists all monotonic binary functions. These are sometimes called Dedekind functions.

What is a binary function? Let $\mathbf{u} = [u_{1}, u_{2}, \cdots u_{N}]$ be a binary valued vector, in which $u_{k} = 0 \text{ or } 1$. A monotonic Boolean function requires $f\left( \mathbf{u} \right) \ge f\left( \mathbf{u^{\prime}} \right)$ if $u_{k} \ge u_{k}^{\prime}$ for each $k$ between $1$ and $N$. There are $2^{M}$ functions, where $M=2^{N}$. Much fewer are monotonic. In the case of $N=2$, there are $16$ different functions, but $6$ of these are monotonic. I pasted an image of the table. In this case, $r_{1}$, $r_{2}$, $r_{4}$, $r_{4}$, $r_{8}$, and $r_{16}$ are monotonic. The term sensor input indicates an input vector $\mathbf{u}=[u_{1}, u_{2}]$ and the term "Global fusion rules" labels the function output.

[[image: This table lists all monotonic functions for vectors <span class=]$\mathbf{u}=[u_{1}, u_{2}]$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYFNb.png).

Comment: [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A000372) has an extensive list of references that might be useful.

Comment: Thank you, @MJD.

Answer (score 1):

If you specify the inputs $u$ (in your notation) which are *minimal*, i.e., $f(u)=1,$ and for all $u'<u, f(u')=0,$ you have completely specified a monotone boolean function (MBF). Simply put, all the inputs $v$ such that $v\geq u$ also satisfy $f(v)=1.$

Such inputs have to be parts of an antichain, i.e., they are incomparable in the boolean algebra of binary strings. For example $u=(1,0,1,0)$ and $u'=(1,1,0,0)$ are incomparable since neither $u'\leq u$ nor $u\leq u'$ holds.

See the beginning of the following [paper](https://www.sfu.ca/%7Etstephen/Papers/r7.pdf) by Stephen and Yusun for a more detailed description to get started.

This reduces your question to the listing of all antichains. See the question [Enumerating all antichains in a finite poset](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380767/enumerating-all-antichains-in-a-finite-poset).